# Multiple bindings for the same action

Tags: tmux

Like many `screen` users I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, so on my machine I changed the binding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, however, I wish to keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> since on some machines it's the default and when sharing work with other people this can be very confusing.

I tried putting two lines in my `.tmux.conf` but only one of them will work.